# how to merge or join pandas pivot table with python

Tags: python, pandas

I try to merge or join two pandas's pivot table
t tried using merge and it does works but the result wasn't i expecting tobe, its giving me duplicate for either table

```py
df1.fillna('', inplace=True)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.fillna('', inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['KEY1', 'KEY2'])
```

First Pivot Table:

```
KEY1    KEY2    KEY3    Column_A0   Column_A1   Column_A2
Row_X0  Row_Y0  Row_Z0  123                     123
        Row_Y1  Row_Z0               456    
                Row_Z1  789                     789
Row_X1  Row_Y0  Row_Z0               123    
                Row_Z1  789     
                Row_Z2  456          789
```

Second Pivot Table:

```
KEY1    KEY2    KEY3    Column_B0   Column_B1   Column_B2   Column_B3
Row_X0  Row_Y0  Row_W0  1           234     
                Row_W1  2           345     
                Row_W2  3           456     
        Row_Y1  Row_W0  4           567         1       234
                Row_W1  7           890         2       345
                Row_W2  8           901         3       456
                Row_W3  9           12          4       567
Row_X1  Row_Y0  Row_W0                          7       890
                Row_W1                          8       901
                Row_W2                          9       12
```

The result I expect:

```
KEY1    KEY2    KEY3_X   Column_A0  Column_A1   Column_A2   KEY3_Y  Column_B0   Column_B1   Column_B2   Column_B3
Row_X0  Row_Y0  Row_Z0   123                    123         Row_W0  1           234     
                                                            Row_W1  2           345     
                                                            Row_W2  3           456     
        Row_Y1  Row_Z0              456                     Row_W0  4           567         1            234
                Row_Z1   789                    789         Row_W1  7           890         2            345
                                                            Row_W2  8           901         3            456
                                                            Row_W3  9           12          4            567
                                                            Row_W0                          7            890
Row_X1  Row_Y0  Row_Z0              123                     Row_W1                          8            901
                Row_Z1   789                                Row_W2                          9            12
                Row_Z2   456                    789
```

is there any i can do to make this happen? thank you

Comment: plz chk your question. better than last question, but still hard to know

Comment: Please show the results you actuallyl got. After you do `reset_index`, why do you expect your DataFrames to have MultiIndex indices?

Comment: Also do you understand what the `how='left'` argument means in the `merge` call?

Answer (score 0):

`Concat()` by row or column. The `pd.concat` function allows you to tables using the column and or row

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).